# Mystery: DateTime precision is rounded when it wants to

Tags: c#, datetime

I've been using time with high precision to log the events of my program in console. But soon I noticed that the program sometimes displays time rounded to milliseconds and sometimes not! It occurs completely sporadically, it's the SAME CODE, NOT RECOMPILED, NOT EDITED BETWEEN RUNS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace DateTimePrecisionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static DateTime ProgramStartTimeGlobal;

        static void PrintConsoleLogGlobal()
        {
            string TimeStampText = ((DateTime.Now - ProgramStartTimeGlobal).TotalMilliseconds / 1000).ToString("0.000000");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Global var: [ {0,10} ] ", TimeStampText));
        }

        static void PrintConsoleLogLocal(DateTime StartTime)
        {
            string TimeStampText = ((DateTime.Now - StartTime).TotalMilliseconds / 1000).ToString("0.000000");
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Local var: [ {0,10} ] ", TimeStampText));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProgramStartTimeGlobal = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                PrintConsoleLogGlobal();
                PrintConsoleLogLocal(ProgramStartTimeGlobal);
                Thread.Sleep(512);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

First I thought it depends whether I'm printing global or local variable. But it doesn't seem to be the case.
The output is (values braces are in seconds):

[image]
[image]

This chaotic precision changes occur in other programs employing this logging. This program, for instance, executes tasks at remote server (with unpredictable delays between them):

[image]  [image]

Why??

Comment: What if you don't divide by 1000 ? You could also use the `Seconds` and `Milliseconds` parts.

Comment: Ok, removed `/ 1000`. It now outputs like this: `[   16348.435900 ]` (so this is milliseconds with 4 digits after period). Now waiting for the stars to align to reproduce rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internally, `DateTime.Now` (via [`UtcNow`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#1cd5dd408a32124f)) depends on the Windows API [`GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately, it would appear (see community comments at bottom of that page) that the resolution of this clock can vary based on the activity of *other* programs on your system.

The [`timeBeginPeriod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is documented as:

> This function affects a global Windows setting. Windows uses the lowest value (that is, highest resolution) requested by any process.

Comment: Wow, that's just astonishing!

Comment: @Taosique - well, if you want any precise timing, you should be using e.g. [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) anyway.

Comment: @Taosique - and it is called out in the [documentation for `Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx): "The resolution of this property depends on the system timer."